# Highlight some custom events on first load Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using `fullCalendar` in my project. My issue is I want to prepopulte the calendar, I am using these settings as

```
initScheduleCalendar = ->
  scheduleCalendar = $('#cloud-recording-calendar').fullCalendar
    axisFormat: 'HH'
    allDaySlot: false
    columnFormat: 'ddd'
    defaultDate: '1970-01-01'
    slotDuration: '00:60:00'
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
    dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
    eventColor: '#428bca'
    editable: true
```

and the days I want to highlight are

```
fullWeekSchedule =
  "Monday": ["08:00-17:30"]
  "Tuesday": ["08:00-17:30"]
  "Wednesday": ["08:00-17:30"]
  "Thursday": ["08:00-17:30"]
  "Friday": ["08:00-17:30"]
  "Saturday": []
  "Sunday": []
```

I want those days pre highlighted on first page load. I dont know whic option is going to be used for this? any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
renderEvents = ->
  schedule = fullWeekSchedule
  days = _.keys(schedule)
  calendarWeek = currentCalendarWeek()

  _.forEach days, (weekDay) ->
    day = schedule[weekDay]
    unless day.length == 0
      _.forEach day, (event) ->
        start = event.split("-")[0]
        end = event.split("-")[1]
        event =
          start: moment("#{calendarWeek[weekDay]} #{start}", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
          end: moment("#{calendarWeek[weekDay]} #{end}", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
        scheduleCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true)

currentCalendarWeek = ->
  calendarWeek = {}
  weekStart = scheduleCalendar.fullCalendar('getView').start
  weekEnd = scheduleCalendar.fullCalendar('getView').end
  day = weekStart
  while day.isBefore(weekEnd)
    weekDay = day.format("dddd")
    calendarWeek[weekDay] = day.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    day.add 1, 'days'
  calendarWeek
```

I did this way.. if anyone interested to know..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by add dayrender function

```
dayRender: function(daysOfWeek, cell) {
        console.log(daysOfWeek._d.toISOString().slice(0,10))
        if (daysOfWeek._d.toISOString().slice(0,10).toString() === '2016-11-24') {
          $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
      }
```

Comment: can you explain little bit more?

Comment: add day render function to your full calendar and day render have two parameters first one the day that will be rendered and the second reference to the cell that contain that day then if the day equals to some date add
highlight class to the cell.